# Result handler not getting control in parsley 3 used with Flex 4 (BlazeDS + Spring)

Tags: apache-flex, remoting, blazeds, parsley

I am using parsley 3 with Flex 4 (AIR) for one of my applications. When I make a remote call I am dispatching an event which reaches till command class and then to Java layer service. Till here all works fine. Java layer makes some call etc and returns result back but my result handler (or fault handler) is not getting control back.

```
 Project
          bin-debug
          libs
              parsley-core-3.0.0.swc
              parsley-flex-3.0.0.swc
              parsley-xml-3.0.0.swc
              spicelib-commands-3.1.1.swc
              spicelib-reflect-3.0.0.swc
              spicelib-util-3.1.0.swc
              spicelib-xml-mapper-3.0.2.swc
         Main.mxml
         ProjectEvent.as
          LoadProjectsCommand
          ProjectPM.as
```

and other stuff.

The command class gets control and also able to call java service. The code is as below:

```
package 
{
    import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
    import mx.controls.Alert;
    import mx.rpc.AsyncToken;
    import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
    import mx.rpc.remoting.RemoteObject;

    /*http://www.spicefactory.org/parsley/docs/3.0/manual/managedcommands.php*/
    public class LoadProjectsCommand
    {
        [Inject(id="projectRemoteService")]
        public var projectRemoteService:RemoteObject;

        [Inject]
        public var model:ProjectScreenPM;

        public function execute(event:ProjectEvent):AsyncToken
        {
            return projectRemoteService.getAllProjectsWithSprintsInSystem() as AsyncToken;
        }

        public function result(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("Result");
        }
        public function fault(event:FaultEvent):void
        {
            Alert.show("Fault in retrieving projects","Error");
        }
    }
}
```

I have verified every thing is fine in Java service call. Can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1):

You might find that the `result` method is not being called because the command is throwing an error.

The failure method in a parsley command is called `error`, not `fault`, so your `fault` method will never be called.

Rename the `fault` method to `error`, and see if that makes a change.

Comment: I found the answer. In parsley 3 I also need to add a responder to the token and now it is working fine. But quite surprisingly, this code is working fine in parsley 2.4.

Comment: If you manually add a responder, then it's your responder that is invoking the fault method, not Parsley.  This is not an appropriate solution, as it will result in the command not being GC'd, which could lead to a memory leak.  Additionally, other `[CommandResult]` or `[CommandError]` handlers wouldn't be invoked.  I suggest you post a question over on the parsley forums, as I haven't made the upgrade from 2.4 to 3.

Comment: I got the reply from Parsley Forum (quite responsive guys over there). The problems are:
1. The handlers should be named as result and error (may be conventions but its fine).
2. The result handler will receive the result itself as the first parameter and if we use the Resultevent as argument, type cast may fail and it wont be executed.
3. And no need to type cast the remote call to AsycnToken as it already is.
The actual post is here:
http://www.spicefactory.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3581

The problem is solved now. Thanks rattkin from the parsley forum.